# Linq to xml extension method with filter

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<GSP>
    <RES>
    <R N="1">
          <FS NAME="date" VALUE="2013-08-26"/>
          <MT N="Title" V="article title"/>
          <MT N="UrlTitle" V="article url title"/>
          <MT N="Description" V="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."/>
          <MT N="IsSpecialArticle" V="true"/>
    </R>
    <R N="2">
          <FS NAME="date" VALUE="2013-08-20"/>
          <MT N="Title" V="article title 2"/>
          <MT N="UrlTitle" V="article url title 2"/>
          <MT N="Description" V="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 2"/>
          <MT N="IsSpecialArticle" V="false"/>
    </R>
   <R N="3">
          <FS NAME="date" VALUE="2013-08-20"/>
          <MT N="Title" V="article title 3"/>
          <MT N="UrlTitle" V="article url title 3"/>
          <MT N="Description" V="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 3"/>
          <MT N="IsSpecialArticle" V="true"/>
    </R>
    </RES>
</GSP>
```

The following code to load into a XElement an xml document:

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Xml/samplexml.xml"));
```

My issue is the following, i dont know how to configure the following sentence in order to get those  items that have a "true" on the V attribute, on the element MT where N="IsSpecialArticle".

```
xElement.Element("RES").Elements("R").Select(??????).Where(???);
```

Do you know how i could archieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards.

jose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xElement
.Element("RES")
.Elements("R")
.Where
(
    x=>
    x
    .Elements("MT")
    .Where
    (
        z=>
        z.Attribute("N").Value == "IsSpecialArticle"
    )
    .Select
    (
        z=>
        z.Attribute("V").Value
    ).SingleOrDefault() == "true"
)
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would load your XML into `XDocument` instead of `XElement`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Xml/samplexml.xml"));
```

And the query:

```
var specialItems = from r in doc.Root.Elements("RES").Elements("R")
                   let mt = r.Elements("MT").FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("N") == "IsSpecialArticle")
                   let isTrue = mt != null && (bool)mt.Attribute("V")
                   where isTrue
                   select r;
```

Comment: Hi Marcing. 

Just one final thing, Why i should use XDocument instead XElement?

Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @Jose3d Because your XML is a document, right? :) Use `XDocument` when you're loading whole document and `XElement` when you're loading XML that is not a correct document.

Comment: There is a `return` clause in linq?

Comment: I think this is a better approach

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var res = (from p in xElement.Element("RES").Elements("R")
           where p.Elements("MT").Any(q => 
                 (string)q.Attribute("N") == "IsSpecialArticle" && 
                 (bool)q.Attribute("V") == true)
           select p).ToArray();
```

We use the `Any()` operator to look "inside" the `R` element and then the various explicit casts of `XAttribute` to convert the attribute values to .NET types.

Note that `(bool)q.Attribute("V") == true` is "too much" :-) `(bool)q.Attribute("V")` would be enough, but I think that in this particular situation, the `== true` makes the expression more readable.

If `V` is optional, you can

```
                 (bool?)q.Attribute("V") == true)
```

note that in this case the `== true` is necessary.